# Derivative of a nonsingular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition

Show that :

$$\frac{d}{dt} A^{-1}(t) = -A^{-1}(t) (\frac{d}{dt} A(t) ) A^{-1}(t) $$

A(t) is a matrix.

Comment: Perhaps an overkill way to do it would be to write $A^{-1}$ as a polynomial in $A$, then differentiate it and do algebra. A hint for how to do this: consider the characteristic polynomial and think about the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Differentiate with respect to $t$ both sides of the equation
$$
A(t) [A(t)]^{-1} = I,
$$
getting (via the product rule)
$$
A(t) \frac{d}{dt} [A(t)]^{-1} + \Bigl(\frac{d}{dt} A(t)\Bigr) [A(t)]^{-1} = 0.
$$
Now multiply both sides of the equation above by $[A(t)]^{-1}$ on the left, getting
$$
\frac{d}{dt} [A(t)]^{-1} = - [A(t)]^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{d}{dt} A(t)\Bigr) [A(t)]^{-1}.
$$